# how to serialize a custom object including Tcpclient (for chatroom userlist)

Tags: c#, serialization

I've created a simple chatroom program .

Basic message sending and receiving works well on the client, and server,too.

But I want to broadcast the connection list to all users when any user leave.

I use a thread to handle this task.

```
    private void monitorProc()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                int bytereads = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                bytereads = clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                updateMonitor(encoder.GetString(buffer), monitor);

            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

And I use this thread like this ...

```
            monitorThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(monitorProc));
            monitorThread.Start();
```

And server is ...

```
    private void broadcast(string message)
    {

        foreach (User user in userlist)
        {
            NetworkStream clientStream;
            clientStream = user.Userclient.GetStream();
            clientStream.Write(encoder.GetBytes(message), 0, 4096);
            clientStream.Flush();

        }
    }
```

When server received message from client , it call this function , and then all user will

In that way , client will put the message when receive message from server.

I define a User class . It contain the following info...

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public enum stat
    {
        ALIVE,
        DEAD
    }
    private string username;
    private IPEndPoint userEP;
    private TcpClient userclient;
    private stat userstat;


    public string Username { get; set; }
    public IPEndPoint UserEP { get { return userEP; } }
    public TcpClient Userclient { get { return userclient; } }
    public stat Userstat { get; set; }

    public User(TcpClient _userclient)
    {
        userclient = _userclient;
        userstat = stat.ALIVE;
    }

}
```

I use a list to store every user in server .

**Question1: how to send the list to every client ?**
(I know that serialization can help . But an error occurred when I use the following code to serialize the list...

```
            foreach (User user in userlist) {
                Stream statBroadcast = user.Userclient.GetStream();
                var bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                bin.Serialize(statBroadcast , userlist);
                connlist.Items.Add(user.Username);
            }
```

**It said that I didn't mark TcpClient as serializable.**

**Question 2: If I can send custom object to client . How to send connection list and message at the same time ?
(If I define a function in client called "updateList" and it receive the data through stream . How to distinct from the data (whether message of connectionlist))**

Comment: Passing a TCP connection from one machine to another doesn't make sense. Change your design...